# Homebutton overwritten, but still finishing when optionmenu is open

Tags: android, back-button, homescreen, overwrite

I have overwritten the functions of the back and the homebutton, to prevent users to use the phone as a phone. We´re giving phones to clients (students) and we don´t want them to abuse the phones in a certain mode.

The thing is, the HOME button is disabled, but when I first open the option menu and then don´t select an option, but press the HOME button, the HOME still works as normal.

Is there anyway to overwrite this and use a boolean, sometimes yes, sometimes no..

What I got now is this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {    
     if (buttonslocked) {
           //backbutton blocked!
        } else {
           super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{  //HOMEBUTTON
    if(buttonslocked)
    {   
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
          super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }
    else
    {
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION); 
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override the home button functionality.

Just as a clarification, although you may see some hacks that *might* provide what you are looking for.. **This is unsupported and discouraged!**

Comment: @LarsDiego: In particular, the techniques outlined in the question do not work as of Android 4.0. If you want control over the HOME button, be a home screen. And, to prevent people from returning to the regular home screen, build your own firmware that has your home screen as the *only* home screen and install it on the devices in question.